# List.Sort exception - Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare() method returns inconsistent results

Tags: c#, list, sorting, icomparer

While trying to perform a List sort, I am getting the following error:

Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare() method returns inconsistent results. Either a value does not compare equal to itself, or one value repeatedly compared to another value yields different results.

Please suggest what might be the likely reasons behind this issue.

Stack Trace:

```
Message: Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare() method returns inconsistent results. Either a value does not compare equal to itself, or one value repeatedly compared to another value yields different results. IComparer: 'Premise.PremiseLIVE.CommGateway.Workflows.Sequential.SequentialWorkflowData.TransportJobPriorityDataSort'.
StackTrace: at System.Collections.Generic.IntrospectiveSortUtilities.ThrowOrIgnoreBadComparer(Object comparer)
at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
at System.Array.Sort[T](T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Sort(Int32 index, Int32 count, IComparer`1 comparer)
at Premise.PremiseLIVE.CommGateway.Workflows.Sequential.WorkflowActivities.wcSortTransportJobs.ExecuteSequential(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
Source: mscorlib
TargetSite: Void ThrowOrIgnoreBadComparer(System.Object)"
```

Code:

```
IComparer<JobPriorityData> comparer = null;
comparer = new TransportJobPriorityDataSort( orgTransportTyps, transportPriorities, false );

if ( comparer != null )
{
    jobList.Sort( comparer );
}

private int _xLTy = -1;
private int _xGTy = 1;
private int _xEQy = 0;

public TransportJobPriorityDataSort( OrgTransportTypCollection orgTransportTyps, TransportPriorityCollection transportPriorities, bool ascending )
{
    _orgTransportTyps = orgTransportTyps;
    _transportPriorities = transportPriorities;

    _ascending = ascending;
    if ( !_ascending )
    {
        _xLTy = 1;
        _xGTy = -1;
    }

    _currentTime = DatabaseTimeHelper.DatabaseUtcTime;
}

public int Compare( JobPriorityData x, JobPriorityData y )
{
    try
    {
        // past-due jobs prioritized over not-past-due.
        if ( ( x.TransportPickupTime.Value <= _currentTime ) && ( y.TransportPickupTime.Value > _currentTime ) )
        {
            return ( _xGTy );
        }
        if ( ( x.TransportPickupTime.Value > _currentTime ) && ( y.TransportPickupTime.Value <= _currentTime ) )
        {
            return ( _xLTy );
        }

        // either: (A) both jobs are past-due or (B) neither job is past-due.

        // Order by Typ
        if ( _orgTransportTyps[ x.JobTransportType ].AssignSeqNbr > _orgTransportTyps[ y.JobTransportType ].AssignSeqNbr )
        {
            return ( _xLTy );
        }
        if ( _orgTransportTyps[ x.JobTransportType ].AssignSeqNbr < _orgTransportTyps[ y.JobTransportType ].AssignSeqNbr )
        {
            return ( _xGTy );
        }

        // then by pickup time
        if ( x.TransportPickupTime < y.TransportPickupTime )
        {
            return ( _xGTy );
        }
        if ( x.TransportPickupTime < y.TransportPickupTime )
        {
            return ( _xLTy );
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception )
    {
    }

    return ( _xEQy );
}
```

Comment: Can you share the source for TransportJobPriorityDataSort ?

Comment: @Mureinik, added the code.

Comment: You've only posted the constructor for the comparer - we need to see the `Compare()` method implementation

Comment: Added the Compare() method.

Comment: That `catch` looks dodgy as

Comment: A sorting comparison method must by reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive, see [Is transitivity required for a sorting algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19013/78816).  Is yours?

Comment: Should the second `if ( x.TransportPickupTime < y.TransportPickupTime )` actually be `if ( x.TransportPickupTime > y.TransportPickupTime )` ? You have two identicial `if` conditions.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, that's a good point. I will check if this makes any difference and will update here accordingly.

Comment: You should not compare against the current time but only compare the two objects against each other.
The first two ifs are the source/reason of/for the error message and should just be removed.
Also, the try-catch should be removed and the comparison be made robust enough to never throw.

Comment: If the try-catch is to catch `NullReferenceException`, there's a standard way to do a `Comparer` that can handle either or both sides being null. First do a `ReferenceEquals`, then check x, then y. And only after that you do the comparison logic. As reference, see how the [String](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7543b056d8ae0654f266b6298e8c14c0fb69f871/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/StringComparer.cs#L311) class does it.